# How to create calculated column with data from same list

Tags: sharepoint-2010, calculated-field

I have a list where user can request amount of 1000 either one time or two time, if user request a amount, sharepoint automatically check with previous amount and subtract from 1000.
suppose: A request 500 one time, next time if i create a list it will check the previous amount and let me know that i can only request 500 max.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, calculated column formulas can only access values from columns on the same list item.

To query the list and retrieve values from other columns, here are a few different options you could consider, depending on your comfort level with the various technologies:

1. Custom Workflow (created using SharePoint Designer or a third-party product like Nintex Workflow or K2).
2. A custom list event handler (created using Visual Studio)
3. A custom form (using InfoPath or a third-party product like Nintex Forms)
4. Custom JavaScript on the New Item form that would override the `PreSaveAction()` method, query the list (using the SharePoint JavaScript Client Side Object Model, SPServices, or REST web services), and return True or False depending on whether you want to allow the item to be created or not

Comment: i said that i need to get the information from same list , not different list, so how can i perform this , i have nintex , if you can let me know which option should i use

Comment: Sorry, you missed a word in my answer: Calculated columns can only access values from columns on the same list **item**.  I'll update my answer with a suggestion for using Nintex Workflow